# UIApplicationExitOnSuspend for Suspend not Background

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application that tends to stay awake in the background due to it playing music; however, on a rare occasion if the music stops between songs for longer than expected(can be relatively short amount of time) due to connectivity issues or the user mutes the music, the application will become suspended. I am aware of `UIApplicationExitOnSuspend` but unlike the description of it, this actually exits on entering background. I have done a fair amount of research, I am aware there are no system notifications for entering suspending state.

Is there anyway to identify on *leaving* suspended state that the app was suspended? Alternatively is there anyways to do something similar to `UIApplicationExitOnSuspend` except only when the application actually is suspended not just when it goes into the background?

Comment: You seem to already have something in mind here that probably won't be possible, as there is no delegate method informing you of a state transition from background to suspended. The docs say explicitly that you should "be prepared to be suspended". Instead of trying to focus on this I'd look for a way to prevent leaving the background state due to connectivity issues or delays and adapt the question accordingly. :) If it's a download task that's not quick enough, try to tweak that and let people here know what you do and how it stops (resulting in the OS thinking you're done and suspend you).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `backgroundtimeremaining` property on UIApplication, poll it with a timer on some interval, and should that value get close enough to zero - set a flag, or even a value in userDefaults, which you could then check and unset after coming back to the foreground?

[The documentation reads:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623029-backgroundtimeremaining)

This property contains the amount of time the app has to run in the background before it may be forcibly killed by the system. While the app is running in the foreground, the value in this property remains suitably large. If the app starts one or more long-running tasks using the beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:) method and then transitions to the background, the value of this property is adjusted to reflect the amount of time the app has left to run.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I ended up making a small class that increments on an interval. Whenever the app comes back from the background it checks how far off the time is from the actual time which seems to do a good job of determining if the app was suspended.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a small class to identify when the app has gone into a suspended state:

```
class SuspendedMonitor {
  static let shared = SuspendedMonitor()

  var delegate: SuspendedMonitorDelegate?

  private let Interval = 10.0

  private let MaxDelta = 2.0

  private var _timestamp: Double

  private var _timer: Timer?

  private init() {
    _timestamp = timeInMs()
  }

  public func start() {
    _timestamp = timeInMs()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(enterForeground),
      name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
      object: nil
    )

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(enterBackground),
      name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground,
      object: nil
    )
  }

  @objc func enterForeground() {
    checkSync()
    _timer?.invalidate()
  }

  @objc func enterBackground() {
    _timestamp = timeInMs()
    setupTimer()
  }

  @objc func incrementTime() {
    _timestamp = _timestamp + (Interval * 1000)
  }

  private func setupTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
      timeInterval: Interval,
      target: self,
      selector: #selector(incrementTime),
      userInfo: nil,
      repeats: true
    )
  }

  private func checkSync() {
    if timeInMs() - _timestamp > ((Interval + MaxDelta) * 1000) { appSuspended() }
  }

  private func appSuspended() {
    delegate?.appDidSuspend(self)
  }

}

protocol SuspendedMonitorDelegate: class {
  func appDidSuspend(_ monitor: SuspendedMonitor)
}
```